# How to consume JavaFX TouchEvent correctly?

Tags: user-interface, layout, javafx

I have a GUI with several menus.
The current menu is the child of a StackPane which in turn is a child of a RootLayout (GridPane) and there is only one menu active at a time which means that the StackPane has only one child at a time.
The menu switches by replacing all children in the StackPane with the new page.
(`theStackpane.getChildren().setAll(newMenu);`)

The active menu may have a button that changes the menu, so a click on the button replaces all children in the StackPane (the one with the button you just clicked as well).

The problem is, when there is a button that changes the menu and there is a button at the same location in the new menu, both buttons get clicked, although you just clicked the first button (which changes the menu).

The structure is like this:

RootLayout
.theStackPane
..activeMenu
...oneButton

A click on oneButton (that changes the menu) leads to:

RootLayout
.theStackPane
..newMenu
...twoButton

The StackPane stays the same, just all children of theStackPane get exchanged by new ones.

Now if oneButton is at the same location of twoButton, oneButton gets activated, changes the menu by replacing all children, newMenu is shown, twoButton gets activated and does whatever it does - stop.

Although I'd like to have it like this:

If oneButton is at the same location of twoButton, oneButton gets activated, changes the menu by replacing all children, newMenu is shown - stop.

How do I prevent the current behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got to a solution:

I got it to work as expected when I switched `setOnTouchPressed` to `setOnAction`.
I don't event need to consume the `ActionEvent` when I touch `oneButton`.

So instead of

```
oneButton.setOnTouchPressed(e -> {
    theStackPane.setAll(newPage);
});
```

I am now using

```
oneButton.setOnAction(e -> {
    theStackPane.setAll(newPage);
});
```

Comment: That's really weird. Maybe it was because something like:
*You touch the screen
*A touchPoint is created
*There's only one touchPoint, so onTouchPressed is fired on buttonOne
*The buttons are changed 
*The touchPoint is still active, so onTouchPressed is fired on buttonTwo
*You stop touching the screen.

I'm not used to work with touch screens so can't be sure how exactly does javaFX works with them. Maybe changing setOnTouchPressed by setOnTouchReleased would also work?

Anyway, at least is working now :D

Comment: Yes, I thought of something like that as well. I guess JavaFX is not grown up enough to be used with touch screens. I did try to use setOnTouchReleased because I thought it would be like, well, you lifted your finger off the screen so why should the second button be pressed but it still got clicked. Thanks for your help though! :D

Answer (score 0):

buttonOne & buttonOnNewPage are inside the same stackPane, right? Then that happens because in the event capturing phase the stackPane propagates the event to both buttons so when the handler tries to consume it, it has already been propagated.

So, instead of using a handler in buttonOne lets try using a filter, and inside it consuming the event. Try something like this:

```
EventHandler filter = new EventHandler(<TouchEvent>() {
    public void handle(TouchEvent event) {
        theStackPane.getChildren().setAll(newPage);
        event.consume();
    }
}
buttonOne.addEventFilter(TouchEvent.TOUCH_PRESSED, filter);
```

Comment: I tried to consume the event before I do anything else in the event handler, it still goes through to the next page.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The two buttons are inside the same StackPane, but not at the same time. There is only one button at that location at a time. I tried creating an EventHandler as you said and adding it as a filter, sadly buttonOnNewPage still got activated...

Comment: Then it seems I don't quite understand what you're trying to do? Could you edit your question and explain a little more about it. Like a short list of steps: what's your layout, what's inside the stack pane, what you do, what happens & what should happen or something like that

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I edited the question above as you said, I hope you can understand it better now.